# React prevent images change name on build (in css)

Tags: reactjs

I have this CSS code for image of a div:

```
#side_login {
  background-image: url("./images/side.png");
}
```

It is relative to the src folder, and it works.
My problem is that after build the image file name changes to something like `side.3acb161b.png`, and for business reasons I prefer to keep it the same (client wants to change the image on the server manually).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: File hash is intentional by react, changing file without changing name would serve old file to existing users because it will be cached.

Comment: The images that I want to use this on are not suppose to change, so caching shouldn't be an issue for them

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: There is a whole discussion in github about it: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9937#issuecomment-853440366